# Flutter null value on non final class variables when fetching from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, null

I am trying to fetch a user document that I have stored in a Firebase document. Even though the document has values for all attributes I can't use the Firebase document to create a proper UserModel instance, because all non final class attributes will be null, which results in "Unexpected null value exception" when trying to use them.

I found out what's happening by logging the fromFirebase method:

```
  factory UserModel.fromFirebase(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final data = (doc.data() as Map?) ?? {};

    print((data['startDate'] as Timestamp?)?.toDate() ?? DateTime.now()); // this line will print the actual value that is stored in the firebase document
    print((data['language'] as String?) ?? 'english'); // this line will print the actual value that is stored in the firebase document

    final userModel = UserModel(
      id: doc.id,
      name: (data['name'] as String?) ?? '',
      photoUrl: (data['photoUrl'] as String?) ?? '',
      email: (data['email'] as String?) ?? '',
      language: (data['language'] as String?) ?? 'english',
      themeMode: data['themeMode'] == null
          ? ThemeMode.system
          : getThemeModeFromString(data['themeMode'] ?? 'system'),
      startDate: (data['startDate'] as Timestamp?)?.toDate() ?? DateTime.now(),
    );

    print(userModel.startDate); // this line will print 'null'
    print(userModel.language); // this line will print 'null'
    
    print(userModel.name) //this line will print the right value
    print(userModel.email) //this line will print the right value

    return userModel;
  }
```

As it seems, all class variables that are marked as final are correctly put into the creation (I tried that via logging too). Can I not design the class to have non final attributes? Am I creating them wrong? I can't think of anything else right now.

Here is some more code. This are my class attributes and constructor:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String email;
  String? language;
  ThemeMode? themeMode;
  DateTime? startDate;

  UserModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.photoUrl,
    required this.email,
    String? language,
    ThemeMode? themeMode,
    DateTime? startDate,
  }); 
...
```

Comment: We can't see this `DocumentSnapshot` object you're working with, so we don't know what this code is going to do when run with.  Please edit the question to show enough information that anyone can use the reproduce the unexpected behavior.  For you, this might involve showing the actual document being used here.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson for that suggestion. Since someone else solved the problem I will leave this question like this now. But for the future I will make sure to provide more complete information for my questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that is your constructor you're asking for some variables but these are not linked to your object, change the constructors by using `this.`

```dart
class UserModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String email;
  String? language;
  ThemeMode? themeMode;
  DateTime? startDate;

  UserModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.photoUrl,
    required this.email,
    this.language,
    this.themeMode,
    this.startDate,
  });
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you! Feels like a super rookie mistake now that I see it. And all the fancy AIs (bard, ChatGPT etc.) couldn't find the mistake either.

Comment: I asked ChatGPT and it does point out the problem and give the exact solution :) (See the last code snippet) https://chat.openai.com/share/1299d6a0-9117-4c22-8c9d-19abd200597d @BenedictKartheuser